# We have a smooth top LG Range. The two left burners only work when one of the right hand burners are on

Tags: electrical

Simple really.  The two left burners only work when one of the right hand burners are turned on as well.

Comment: Do you have any other 240V appliances? Do you have a voltmeter?

Comment: What country are you in?  How is the stove wired? Do you have 3-phase power?

Comment: What model of range? Is it a brand new install or has it been working properly for a period of time prior?

Comment: Is this a new problem or has it always been this way ? I have seen this after a control switch change where the terminals were not marked the same. Like putting the hot on the wrong side of a light switch with multiple switches so the others only work when 1 is on.